# only first 50 rows are getting copied to clipboard from datagridview in winforms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, copy-paste

I have a datagridview myDgv to which data will be filled from database.

I am doing a Ctrl+A (select all) and copying ( Ctrl + C )
when I paste the copied data into excel, only first 50 rows of data is getting copied.
Rest of the rows comes blank.

Here is the code in my keydown event

```
If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.C Then
    Dim d As DataObject = myDgv.GetClipboardContent()
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(d)
    e.Handled = True
End If
```

when I scroll down the grid till end (last row) and do Ctrl+C and then paste it in excel,
all the rows are getting pasted.

How do I proceed to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm slightly puzzled. The DataGridView supports CTRL-A and CTRL-C natively. You should not need to write a single line of code to copy the data. You can also set how the copy is done using the ClipboardCopyMode property.

Answer (score 0):

use `DataGridView.SelectAll` Method to select all rows on using ctrl + A.

and use following event to get key pressed:

```
void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
    {
        //call to DataGridView.SelectAll Method
    }
}
```

Comment: in Ctrl + A I already handled select all
I even tried adding this line ( which selects all again )
but still same result. Blank lines are appearing.
I guess those lines are not getting loaded into buffer.

Comment: have you changed clipboardcopymode of datagridview to EnableWithoutHeaderText?